# JMeter: Sampler results shows “Sample Start: 1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST”

Tags: java, date, selenium, junit, jmeter

I am trying to reuse a simple script written in JUnit to hit ***www.google.com*** in JMeter, however, Invalid Date/Time is displayed in Sampler Result as “Sample Start: 1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST” .

My System Date/Time is up to date and same Date/Time is not displayed for others scripts.

Please Refer JMeter Script:

[image: Sampler Result]

Also,

1. JUnit .jar script is added to JMeter/lib/junit
2. Selenium and JUnit .jar files are added to JMeter/lib

[image: JUnit Script]

Please help as I am stuck to this point and could not get desired suggestions yet from google.

Comment: Please add a Debug Sampler and tell us what the value is for the variable `START.MS=`.

Comment: @djangofan The Response Date from Debug Sampler is: JMeterVariables:
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=false
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@59761ebe
START.HMS=102956
START.MS=1426827596923
START.YMD=20150320
TESTSTART.MS=1426827757952

Comment: You can tell from the START.HMS and the START.YMD variables, that your system time is ok.

Comment: @djangofan  Thanks for the valuable information on Debug Sampler, however, I would also like to know how can I overcome the issue which I am facing with Sampler Request.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it works for me.  You must be doing something unusual, either with your Java that your running jmeter with, the version of the plugins you installed, or by adding a 3rd party library that conflicts with something else.

Comment: Could you please let me know which Version of JMeter, Eclipse you used. My details are:     1) JMeter: Tried with 2.11, 2.12 and 2.13
    2) junit-4.12
    3) selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0
    4)Eclipse: Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73400/discussion-between-priyanka-and-djangofan).

Answer (score 0):

- Well, trying against a site like google.com always gave me a wrong results, Please try performing the tests on some site on which you have an authority/control ( just my honest opinion) , because we may need to check few settings on local and  server as well
- please check for plugins you may have installed and ensure there are no conflicts in the libraries you are using.
- please refer to documentation available at https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf

Comment: I tried with other link too but that does not work. When there is value to be Printed then it works but when there is a link to hit, that time same issue is appearing.

Comment: I am using updated Eclipse 4.4.2, junit-4.12 and selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0

Comment: I tried replicating it but was not able to, I posted to nabble forum, this is an interesting topic, In case I get any update, will let you know

Comment: Mean while, please ensure you are using the latest version of Jmeter

Comment: Sure Revanth, even I will update you if this issue is resolved. However, I used latest version of Eclipse, JUnit Jar file, Selenium Jar file and JMeter too but still the same. Thanks!

Comment: This question was not accepted by jmeter - [forum](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Junit-Date-Time-Issue-td5722344.html)